# Android Drawable Image not Showing

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to programically set the background of my app with an image in my drawable-hdpi folder. It is only seeing the default ic_launcher file in R.drawable so when I go to set the background, its simply unexistant. I am using this class as a fragment class with a swipe menu so maybe that has something to do with it.

EDIT: I was able to set the background in my xml file, but I couldn't set the background in my oncreateview method.

```
public class inputClass extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_xml, container, false);

    rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hidden);


    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your drawable image file is only available `drawable-hdpi` folder. In order to set the background properly, you can do two following ways.

1. You should place your image file to all drawable directories. I mean you should put that image into `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and so on. Also you should be careful about the size of the image because each folder corresponds to screen sizes. Please check out this [API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
2. Second way is the alternative for the first one. Create a directory within `res/` folder and name it as `drawable` and then move your image file from `drawable-hdpi` to `drawable`.

Then, clean the project and relaunch.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 4):

If you extend your activity from `Activity`, then using `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`.

This is solved a problem in my case.

Comment: But you can't use `src` attribute if your drawable is a `VectorDrawable`