# Drawable not displayed when id is loaded dynamically and application signed

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-resources

**Context**

Each item in a listview loads an image. Given the item's data the id for the resource(drawable) is returned. This id is used in the imageview's setResourceId.

**Problem**

When the apk is signed, nothing is displayed ( however no error occurs).

**Testing**

Ensuring the correct id for the resource is loaded. One item was created whose matching resource is *R.drawable.banana*, the *id* returned by the function was logged as well as the value *R.drawable.banana* (shown below).

```
int id = CropDataHelper.getCropsDrawable(myContext, txt);
Log.i("image id:"+id,"found id Fragment View Cycles");
Log.i("raw draw:"+R.drawable.banana,"drawable Fragment View Cycles");
```

The values logged were the same hence the correct id was being returned.

**Further Testing Reveals**

If using the resource directly, R.drawable.example the image is displayed, even though the function returns the same value.

```
id = R.drawable.banana;
...
iv.setImageResource(id);
```

**Previous Failed attempts**

- **Putting resource into a different folders (no-dpi, etc)**

[folder attempt reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25828601/2950743). However since the image does show if I use the
   direct *R reference* this was a baseless attempt.

- **Using the drawable resource**

Use the *id* attained to load the drawable directly and set it.

```
Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(myContext,id);
...
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

**Actual Code Snippet**

```
int id = CropDataHelper.getCropsDrawable(myContext, txt);
Log.i("image id:"+id,"found id Fragment View Cycles");
Log.i("raw draw:"+R.drawable.banana,"drawable Fragment View Cycles");
//              id = R.drawable.banana; - testing use of direct resource
//              Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(myContext,id); drawable attempt
ImageView iv = ((ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon_purchaseType));
if (id != -1) {
    iv.setImageResource(id);
//                  iv.setImageDrawable(d); - drawable attempt
}
```

**Final Remarks**

The problem does not occur while debugging, only on a signed apk, this leads me to believe there is some underlying permissions that *R.drawable.example* unlocks on a signed apk but when trying to use the id directly these permissions are not unlocked. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Work Around**

Hashmap of string names to *R*'s ids

**Reasoning**

It seems there may have been some permission not available when trying to read the files (Only occurs in signed - even though these are app images). To work around this, instead of using a json file to load image files by name, A hashmap was created with strings to match *R*'s ids.

**Sample Code**

```
//create hashmap
private HashMap<String,Integer> resources;

//fill hash map with resources
resources.put("FIRST",R.drawable.example_img_1);
resources.put("SECOND",R.drawable.example_img_2);

//simple method to access resources
public Integer getResourceId(String key){
    if(resources.containsKey(key))
        return resources.get(key);
    return R.drawable.default_image;
}
```